# R: Use circlize to make Chord diagram using overlapping row and column name

Tags: r, diagram, chord

I have a data frame like this:
[image]

When I tried to make a chord diagram, I get six sectors instead of 3 sectors for A, B, C.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi Taliman, please add your code (and an easy way to cut/paste your data, for example using `dput`) so that the example is reproducible and we can quickly produce the same chart you are trying to fix above. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi. I have solved the problem. Could you remove this question please?